# Locking QGIS project file?

Tags: qgis-2.18, lock, qgs

Is it possible to lock a QGIS project file, so only I can open it with a password?

I work with a QGIS 2.18 version and I'm looking for a solution inside the QGIS software. in my map, i use only with regular layers and use not PostGIS.
I red [Password Protect QGIS project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157656/password-protect-qgis-project) and it didn't answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could zip it with a password. That way it will not be accessible without authorization.

Because OP didn't provide any information of an OS, assumption is that windows is the current system environment.

[how to lock a file](https://superuser.com/questions/294826/how-to-purposefully-exclusively-lock-a-file)