# Password protect QGIS project file (.qgz)

Tags: qgis-3, password

I want to password protect my QGIS Project file (.qgz).

Goal: Without password no one can open or modify it. Maybe a read/write or just write protection.

I can't find an option in QGIS. Any idea? Did I missed the option in settings?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157656/password-protect-qgis-project/157664

Comment: yes I read this. No other Option than this?

"You could try your hand at running a Python script on project open that might ask for credentials, though in the 5 minutes I spent trying that, could not get this to work. Check out Project Properties (CTRL+Shift+P) and then Macros to see what I mean."